# Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use - but the database is deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Has anyone run into this error even when the database is deleted? I deleted the database and checked the "close existing connections" box before deleting.

I have a Live db and a Test Db. I have made a backup of Live. When I try to restore Live.bak to a database with name Test, I get the exclusive access error. I need to copy the Live db over Test.

Funny thing is I can restore a backup of Test if needed.

Comment: Can you share your restore statement? Have you included the MOVE clause so that you're not trying to overwrite the existing Live files?

Comment: I'm just using the GUI. I have a Live.bak and I restore it to Test. I am not overwriting anything in the Live db as far as I know.

Comment: If you don't change the filepaths for the data & log files then they could still be pointing at the location of the live files (even though you've changed the database name), you can check this on the 'Files' tab of the restore GUI, or by scripting the restore statement & checking for a MOVE clause.

Comment: Thanks! By scripting I figured out I was trying to take a backup of the live log before restoring and this was causing the failure :) I unchecked tail log backup and it worked

Comment: Ha, yeah that'd do it too. Scripting it always a good idea so you can check exactly what the GUI thinks it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to close existing connections before deleting

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Reattach it with same name and rename the database. Or restore with `norecovery`

```
RESTORE DATABASE TEST FROM DISK = 'C:\Live.BAK' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG TEST FROM DISK = 'C:\LIVELOG.trn'
```

-- Moving file lcoations

```
WITH MOVE 'MDFLogicalName' TO 'C:\test.mdf',
MOVE 'LDFLogicalname' TO 'D:\Test.ldf'
```

Comment: Thanks. Seeing your statement helped me realize I was trying to perform a log backup on the Live db. This was the cause for the failure :)

Comment: :) Anyways i have added Move command aswel if u need to move mdf and ldf file names across as suggested by @GarethLyons

Comment: i would recommend altering it back to SET MULTI_USER at the end.